# views argument in the empty text field

Tags: drupal, drupal-views

i am using the views 2 module.
i have a view that gets a taxonomy term as an argument.
i want my view to display a text, in case there are no found items, "Cannot find any $args[0]".
where $args[0] is the view argument.
but  i cant figure out a way to add php code to the empty text configuration, i can see it supports filtered and full html, but no php code option.
any help ?
and if we are on the subject,
how can i add a view page display that has an argument to a drupal menu ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to run php code in order to create your markup, you should really do it in a custom module, which is probably the reason that views doesn't support it. You could create a custom module, and do the check yourself and use `views_embed_view` to display the view you want, or just create the page yourself if the argument is not found or invalid.

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable the 'php filter' module under core modules.  That is for drupal 6.  Then you will have the php option for input type in your views ui.